# Entity Framework collection is empty after obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I have the following code:

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public virtual Company WorksForCompany { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WorksForCompany")]
    public int? WorksForCompanyId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Companies")]
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("WorksForCompany")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the obfuscation rules are correct because none of the above types or properties are renamed or deleted. I have verified this with ILSpy. Still the following code returns the correct result after building, but the list is empty when running the obfuscated build.

```
Assert.AreEqual(4, company.Employees.Count());
```

EF logging shows that the SQL query to fill the `Employees` list is not executed before testing the number of list items. The type of `company` is the dynamic proxy class, and the type of `Employees` is `List<Employee>` in both cases.

What could be broken so that the list isn't filled anymore? What more can I check to find out what's different? Any interesting runtime types to look at?

Comment: What do you mean by obfuscation? The attributes? Those are called data annotations. BTW, do you do code first? Then the `Table`  and `Key` annotations aren't necessary: EF will come up with the same names and keys by convention.

Comment: I do mean code obfuscation, with Dotfuscator. And yes, it's code first. The attributes are just there to specify the table names. Not sure whether they are required here. The database schema is from an older system. I don't use EF migrations.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but do you run the obfuscated version against the same database?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I've looked into it. The application writes these entries itself before.